# OpenID lib in C++?

Tags: c++, openid, openssl

I need to use openid in a c++ website and can't find a working library to work with.
I am trying to use this one
http://kin.klever.net/libopkele/requirements

but it stops the configure with this message:
checking for OPENSSL... configure: error: no openssl library found. get one from http://www.openssl.org/

but my debian has openssl installed and libssl-dev libssl installed...

any help please?
Thanks,
Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examining configure, it looks like [pkg-config](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/pkg-config) is needed for libopkele to find the openssl.

```
aptitude install pkg-config
```