# Is out there any windows library for pure C++ applications (not .net) that would work as openID client?

Tags: c++, windows, openid

I want to create simpe native windows app in C++ thet would work as openID client. I wonder if out there are any openID C++ libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried KIN::libopkele, referenced in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632444/openid-lib-in-c)?

Comment: As you can see I need a library buildable and supported on\for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The thing I can find is this: http://kin.klever.net/libopkele/

Comment: Are there any totorials on its compilation for windows? Are there any other libs for C++?

Comment: Here is one attempt to build for Visual C++ on Windows:
http://orenosv.com/blog/2008/08/24/windows-port-of-libopkele-openid-library-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally tried it on windows, but I know people have — http://orenosv.com/blog/2008/08/24/windows-port-of-libopkele-openid-library-in-c/ — hope this will be of help.